# How can I get custom objects from spark.sql.Row

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question: is it possible to get custom object from spark.sql.Row?

Current code is able to push data to Spark ROW, but I can't extract it back.

First of all there is a simple POJO object:

```
public class Event implements Serializable {

  private Map<String, Object> fields;

  public Event() {
  }

  public Event(Map<String, Object> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getFields() {
    return fields;
  }

  public void setFields(Map<String, Object> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
  }
}
```

As a next step we create JavaDStream of Tuple2(String, Event) using Spark Streaming API. After that we convert each RDD to Dataset.

```
 JavaDStream<Tuple2<String, Event>> events = ...

    events.foreachRDD(tuple2JavaRDD -> {

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(tuple2JavaRDD.context().conf()).getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> dataSet = sparkSession.createDataset(tuple2JavaRDD.rdd(),
                Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.bean(Event.class))).toDF("EventType", "Event");

        //try to get data back
        Dataset<Event> eventsSet = dataSet.map((MapFunction<Row, Event>) row ->  row.<Event>getAs(1), Encoders.bean(Event.class));

         //and getting an exception when try to get the element from stream 
         eventsSet.show();
    }); 
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to Event

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
eventsSet.select("Event").as(Encoders.bean(Event.class));
```

For your code you should construct objects step by step:

```
...
Event event = new Event();
event.setFields(row.getAs(...));
return event;
```